# Excel - Easiest way to identify empty columns

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have a formula like this: =COUNTBLANK(BA3:BA21771)/ROWS(BA3:BA21771)
I have columns that extend all the way out to KM.
I really don't want to have modify each column's formula like so:

=COUNTBLANK(BA3:BA21771)/ROWS(BA3:BA21771)
=COUNTBLANK(BB3:BB21771)/ROWS(BB3:BB21771)
=COUNTBLANK(BC3:BC21771)/ROWS(BC3:BC21771)

There must be an easier way! Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with Edit->Fill Right?

Comment: Nope. I am apparently an Excel moron.

Comment: @matt Don't feel so. Some tricks in Excel are not evident until you see them working. The manual and help don't help much, just because they boringly describe some GUI procedure until you are lost. Try finding some videos "Excel for Morons" :D

Answer (score 0):

You can "Fill Right" from the original formula, and it will copy the formula with an updated column label.

Highlight the cell with the formula, and then using the black + at the bottom right of the cell, drag the box right to fill in the other columns.  Each column will have the same formula, but will replace BA with BB, BC, BD, and so on.

If you need to anchor a column, you can use the '$' prefix, e.g. $BA.